# How To Get Column Description

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, in a [emp] table, the columns are :

```
emp_id    emp_name    emp_role
```

If the values being inserted in `emp_role` column values can be 0 (for Administrator), 1 (for Management), 2 (for Employees).

Now is there any way to get those details of a column `emp_role` (like, 0 for Administrator) along with the table concerned (i.e, `[emp]`) in SQL server database ?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is not unless you know the structure and relationships of your database. You should review the following concepts: Table, Primary Key, Foreign Key and Relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If you have dictionary table with role definitions it will be something similar to:

```
select e.emp_id, e.emp_name, r.name
from emp e
inner join role r on e.emp_role = r.id
```

if not, but you know role names it will be something similar to:

```
select emp_id, emp_name, 
case emp_role when 0 then 'Administrator' when 1 then 'Management' when 2 then 'Employees' end as RoleName
from emp
```